# About Call to a member function domain() on a non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a question about Laravel 5.  After using `Form::open`, some error occurs:

```
error : Call to a member function domain() on a non-object

FatalErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 440:
Call to a member function domain() on a non-object
in UrlGenerator.php line 440
at HandleExceptions->fatalExceptionFromError(array('type' => '1', 'message' => 'Call to a member function domain() on a non-object', 'file' => '/home/nl/Laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php', 'line' => '440')) in HandleExceptions.php line 116
at HandleExceptions->handleShutdown()
```

This is my LoginCheckController.php:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class LoginCheckController extends BaseController {

    public function index()
```

This is my route:

```
Route::post('/LoginCheck', 'LoginCheckController@index');
```

In view I have this:

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'LoginCheckController@index')) !!}
```

I also ran `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan clear-compiled`, but I still get the error. Is there something I forgot?

I solved it by:

1. Re-installing composer with clear version
2. php artisan make:controller with manual

Comment: What file and line does that error occur in?

Comment: the error like above thanks .

Comment: You need to tell us what version you are using. The latest on the 5.0 branch on GitHub does not have anything relevant on line 440: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L440 Also a search for a call to `domain` (`->domain(`) returns nothing relevant in that file: https://github.com/laravel/framework/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=-%3Edomain%28

Comment: sorry , for laravel I still a new , how to check my Illuminate/Routing/…version ?

Answer (score 0):

Try including the namespace in the action:

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'App\Http\Controllers\LoginCheckController@index')) !!}
```

http://laravel.io/forum/10-03-2014-laravel-5-call-to-a-member-function-domain-on-a-non-object

Answer (score 0):

First update your laravel framework package, looking at the line you're running behind.

Second, in Laravel 5 everything is lives in the `App` namespace, your controllers are in `App\Http\Controllers\`. The routes are working because of the namespace for it being set in the `RouteServiceProvider`.

Try adding the namespace in your template when using `action`, or use named routes like this:

```
Route::post('/LoginCheck', ['uses' => 'LoginCheckController@index', 'as' => 'login.check.index']);

{!! Form::open(['route' => 'login.check.index']) !!}
```

Comment: Sorry , thanks your help , but still not work , or I don't how to use it ?
could give a sample code for refer ><

Comment: Did you update the laravel package? Run `composer update` in your terminal. And are you getting the same error or something else?

Comment: now it occur follow ~


in compiled.php line 7717
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST')) in compiled.php 

line 7713
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('POST')) in compiled.php line 7691
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 6965
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 6937

Comment: Do a `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan optimize` and try again

Comment: I solve it , I re composer laravel5 with clear version , then re-above these step , thanks a lot